# Selecting using MATCH-AGAINST and IN in MySQL query?

Tags: php, mysql, syntax-error, match-against

I have the following query in PHP:

```
$titlematch = mysql_query("SELECT `item_id` FROM `items` WHERE `item_id` IN ($matches_s) AND MATCH (`eng_name`) AGAINST ('$query') IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE AS score;");
$titlematch2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($titlematch);
```

In plain words, I want to select the `item_id` from the table `items` where

1. the `item_id` value can be found within the array `$matches_s`, and
2. the string stored in `eng_name` can be found within the string `$query`

and then output a 2-dimensional array, where the second-level array contains the `item_id` and `score` (relevance) elements.

I have tried switching the order of which criteria comes first, or using brackets. Here are the results I get:

```
var_dump($titlematch); // returns bool(false)
var_dump($titlematch2); // returns NULL
```

Question is **'What am I doing wrong? Do I have to write this differently to other `AND` statements?**

Comment: Have you checked with `mysql_error()` if the syntax was invalid perhaps?

Comment: @mario really sorry but how do you do that? I tried `echo mysql_error($titlematch);` but nothing came back...